# 2 out of 3 property of fibrations?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, projective-space, fibration

Let $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ be a diagram in the category of topological spaces. If $g\circ f$ and one of $f,g$ are fibrations, can we conclude that so is the other?

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233165/fibration-factorization-leads-to-new-fibrations) it is stated that if $f$ is surjective and $g\circ f$ and $f$ are fibrations then $g$ is a fibration. However, no proof is given there. Is this true? How do I prove it? I understand that the main difficulty is that an arbitrary map $W\to Y$ may not be lifted along $f$ to a map $W\to X$. I'm not sure whether this lifting property is true...

The motivation for this problem is that I want to show that $\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{CP}^{n}$ and $\mathbb{CP}^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{HP}^n$ are fibrations. I know that there are fibrations (in fact fiber bundles) $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}$ and $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{CP}^n$ and the factorization of these two maps gives the map $\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{CP}^{n}$. I wonder if we could use the above property to deduce directly that $\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{CP}^{n}$ is a fibration.

Comment: If $g$ is a constant map (map to a point), then so is $g \circ f$, and both are fibrations. If there was a 2 out of 3 property, you would be able to conclude that any map $f$ is a fibration.

Comment: @Lorenzo That isn't true. Take any path from the point in the image to some other point. There is always a lift of the initial map, but there can't be a lift of the homotopy.

Comment: Are you talking about Hurewicz fibrations or Serre fibrations ? In the latter case  you should be able to lift $W\to Y$ to $W\to X$ when $W$ is nice enough, hence get the Serre fibration (that's where you would use surjectivity of $f$ by the way)

Comment: @Max Hurewicz fibration.

Comment: @ConnerMalin I meant the case when Z is itself a point.

Comment: @Lorenzo Of course you are right. My mistake.